# How to verify a kernel module signature?

Tags: kernel, kernel-modules, signature

When you compile a kernel source, you can choose to sign kernel modules using the `CONFIG_MODULE_SIG*` options. The `modinfo` tool should handle the task of verifying the module signature, but there has been some bug in it for years, and the tool simply can't do the job anymore. All I get is the following:

```
sig_id:         PKCS#7
signer:
sig_key:
sig_hashalgo:   md4
signature:      30:82:02:F4:06:09:2A:86:48:86:F7:0D:01:07:02:A0:82:02:E5:30:
                ...
```

So there's no key and the hash algorithm is md4, which isn't even compiled in the kernel.

So how to manually check and verify the module signature? Is that even possible?

Comment: What kernel version is this? It must be quite old to be using such an outdated hash algorithm.

Comment: According to [this page](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.10/admin-guide/module-signing.html), public keys are stored under `/proc/keys`. Have you looked there? See the section on 'Public keys in the kernel'.

Comment: The kernel isn't old, it's 4.20. The `md4` algorithm is shown because of a `kmod` bug and it's been there for 2-3 years at least: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1320921

Comment: I know that the key is in `/proc/keys` , but how to check the module sig using it. I also have a private/public key which was used to sign the modules. How to verify the sig manually

Comment: I haven't used it a lot, but I believe signature verification can be done using [`gpg`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Privacy_Guard). You will probably have to add the public key to its database. [This page](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2013/04/gnupg-digital-signatures/) seems to provide some useful information.

Comment: You say it's only showing 'md4' because of a bug? So, do you know what the actual hash algorithm is?

Comment: Yes: `CONFIG_MODULE_SIG_HASH="sha512"`.

Comment: I don't think GPG can be used to verify the sig.

Comment: Why not? Have you tried it? Looks like it should be `gpg --verify [signature] [module file]`. https://www.gnupg.org/gph/en/manual/r697.html (although I think you have to add the key too the gpg database)

Comment: Read this: https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Signed_kernel_module_support

Comment: Ok, fair enough. Thought I'd just throw out what I could think of.

Comment: @MikhailMorfikov for the strange output from modinfo, I guess [this](https://github.com/lucasdemarchi/kmod/commit/a11057201ed326a9e65e757202da960735e45799) answers it: "when PKC#7 signing method is used the old structure doesn't contain
any useful data"; if you build a new version of kmod from source, modinfo will print `unknown` instead of `md4` for `sig_hashalgo`.

Comment: So there's no way to check the sig manually now?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, that's possible, but it's quite involved.

First you have to extract the module signature -- you can use the [`extract-module.sig.pl`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/scripts/extract-module-sig.pl?id=d01c3289e7d68162e32bc08c2b65dd1a216a7ef8) script from the kernel source for that:

```
$ scripts/extract-module-sig.pl -s MODULE.ko >/tmp/modsig.
Read 789006 bytes from module file
Found magic number at 789006
Found PKCS#7/CMS encapsulation
Found 670 bytes of signature [3082029a06092a864886f70d010702a0]
```

Second, you have to extract the certificate and public key from the kernel; you can use the [`extract-sys-certs.pl`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/scripts/extract-sys-certs.pl?id=d01c3289e7d68162e32bc08c2b65dd1a216a7ef8) script for that:

```
$ scripts/extract-sys-certs.pl /PATH/TO/vmlinux /tmp/cert.x509
Have 32 sections
Have 28167 symbols
Have 1346 bytes of certs at VMA 0xffffffff81be6db8
Certificate list in section .init.data
Certificate list at file offset 0xde6db8
$ openssl x509 -pubkey -noout -inform der -in /tmp/cert.x509 -out /tmp/pubkey
```

You can also extract the public key from the `certs/signing_key.x509` or `certs/signing_key.pem` files from the linux kernel's build directory.

Having done that, you have all the data you need in `/tmp/modsig` and `/tmp/cert.x509` and can continue with the dozen or so steps necessary to verify a PKCS#7 signature.

You can look at this blog [post](http://qistoph.blogspot.com/2012/01/manual-verify-pkcs7-signed-data-with.html) for the whole recipe.

---

I've tried to put the whole process (except for the `extract-certs.pl` step) in a perl script.

You can use it like this:

```
perl checkmodsig.pl /path/to/cert.x509 mod1.ko mod2.ko ...
```

**YMMV**. I've only tried this with a custom built kernel using sha512 signatures. This should be of course much better done by using the openssl libraries directly, instead of kludging together slow and fragile `openssl x509`, `asn1parse` and `rsautl` invocations.

**checkmodsig.pl**

```
use strict;

sub through {
    my ($cmd, $data, $cb) = @_;
    use IPC::Open2;
    my $pid = open2 my $from, my $to, ref $cmd ? @$cmd : $cmd;
    print $to $data; close $to; my $out;
    if($cb){ while(<$from>){ last if $out = $cb->($_) } }
    else { local $/; $out = <$from>; }
    waitpid ($pid, 0);
    die "status $?" if $? != 0;
    $out;
}
sub gethash {
    my ($d) = @_; my ($alg, $hash);
    through [qw(openssl asn1parse -inform der)], $d, sub {
        if(/(\d+):d=\d+ +hl= *(\d+) +l= *(\d+) +prim: +OCTET STRING/){
            $hash = substr $d, $1 + $2, $3
        }elsif(/prim: +OBJECT +:(sha\w+)/){
            $alg = $1;
        }
        undef
    };
    $alg, $hash
}

use File::Temp;
my $tf = new File::Temp;
my $pub_key;
my @type = qw(PGP X509 PKCS7);
my $r = 0;
if((my $cert = shift) =~ /(\.x509)$|\.pem$/i){
    $pub_key = $tf->filename;
    system qw(openssl x509 -pubkey -noout),
        '-inform', $1 ? 'der' : 'pem',
        '-in', $cert, '-out', $pub_key;
    die "status $?" if $? != 0;
}
die "no certificate/key file" unless $pub_key;
for my $kof (@ARGV){
    open my $ko, '<', $kof or die "open $kof: $!\n";
    seek $ko, -4096, 2 or die "seek: $!";
    read $ko, my $d, 4096 or die "read: $!";
    my ($algo, $hash, $type, $signer_len, $key_id_len, $sig_len, $magic) =
        unpack 'C5x3Na*', substr $d, -40;
    die "no signature in $kof"
        unless $magic eq "~Module signature appended~\n";
    die "this script only knows about PKCS#7 signatures"
        unless $type[$type] eq 'PKCS7';

    my $hash = gethash substr $d, - 40 - $sig_len, $sig_len;
    die "hash not found" unless $hash;

    my ($alg, $vhash) = gethash
        through [qw(openssl rsautl -verify -pubin -inkey), $pub_key],
            $hash;

    seek $ko, 0, 0 or die "seek: $!";
    read $ko, my $d, (-s $ko) - $sig_len - 40 or die "read: $!";
    use Digest::SHA;
    my $fhash = new Digest::SHA($alg)->add($d)->digest;

    if($fhash eq $vhash){
        print "OK $kof\n";
    }else{
        print "**FAIL** $kof\n";
        $r = 1;
        warn 'orig=', unpack('H*', $vhash), "\n";
        warn 'file=', unpack('H*', $fhash), "\n";
    }
}
exit $r;
```